# How to display the highest score in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I would like to display the highest score player after several rounds. 
Here is the table:

```
PlayerID   Round   number of score
   1         1           4
   2         1           5
   3         1           8
   1         2           3
   2         2           10
   3         2           7
```

Expected Output

```
PlayerID         number of score
   2                     15
   3                     15
```

I have tried this code, but here is error. How can I display the output?

```
SELECT playerID , MAX(SUM(numberOfGoals)) FROM Game;
```

Comment: Read about the `Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) for an overview.

Answer (score 3):

**TRY THIS:**

```
SELECT playerID,  SUM(numberOfGoals) AS numberOfGoals
FROM Game
GROUP BY playerID
HAVING SUM(numberOfGoals) IN (SELECT MAX(goals) FROM (SELECT SUM(numberOfGoals) goals 
FROM Game GROUP BY playerID) t)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: I have tested it in `sql server` and working fine as expected. It's surprising to not to work in `mysql` can you please try with `=` instead of `IN`

Comment: subQuery will return only for max score value records

Comment: Yes it should return `15` then the outer query returns the record whose sum of goals equal to `15` that is  playerID- `2,3`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it displays all the players with added score but not displaying the highest score player

Comment: @Suraz  [**Results** exactly like the Questions sample output!](https://image.ibb.co/dTaHWR/results2.jpg)  ...[this is kinda fun]  ;-)

Comment: @WILLIAM actually after the correction for SQL Server -> MySQL, it returns exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @Suraz Thank you so much. Now it work. One more question, why do we need to put "t" at the end of the query

Comment: It's an alias name for the result set of sub query and we are selecting `goals` from that so we must give it the alias name.

Comment: @WILLIAM It's my pleasure. if you find this answer really useful then please accept it so it will be helpful to others also.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT playerId, Sum(numberofscore)
FROM Game 
Group By PlayerId
Order By Sum(numberofscore) Desc
```

Comment: this doesn't exactly get the solution he is looking for. It gives all scores in a sorted order. You could use `TOP` to get it closer to the answer. But will not give all the top results

Comment: You can set limit if you want first 2 numberofscore
`SELECT playerId , Sum(numberofscore) FROM Game Group By PlayerId Order By Sum(numberofscore) Desc limit 2 `

Comment: well you can hard code it to a hard coded number. But that is not what he is looking for. He needs to dynamically find all in the top most score. Once you make limit dynamic, the only way I see is using one more select. Using an inline query would defeat the whole purpose of using the order by trick

Comment: this will return top most score first with Descending values

Comment: yep. my point exactly. It will only return the top most value. He wants all records with the topmost values. Can't be done with a hard coded 2

Comment: yes that is why I have not added limit in answer, As he shown two records only therefore i have commented for if he wants to set the limit then he can set. :)

Comment: well neither ways gives him what he is looking for

Comment: @Damini-Suthar  (There's some results!)[https://image.ibb.co/iQLed6/results.jpg] :-)